# How to remove click event handler?

Tags: jquery

In the js code below, when the user clicks a link they should be given a confirmation modal to approve the action.

However, there is a bug where if the user clicks a link, the confirmation modal is shown, then if they click another link another modal appears. If they confirm that modal 2 requests are sent.

How can I remove the click events of other links when a Modal is open?

```
$(function () {

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $('a[data-bs-toggle="modal"][requires-confirmation]').on('click', function (e) {
       
      //***************************************
      //trying to prevent click event propagation
      //***************************************

         e.stopPropagation();
         e.preventDefault();
      //***************************************
        var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
        
        var hasDataDelete = $(this).is('[data-delete]');
        var deleteAction = $(this).attr('data-delete') === 'true';

        $('#confirmModal').modal('show');

        $("#errorContainer").hide();
        $('#confirmMessage').show();
        $('#confirmButton').show();
    
        if (deleteAction) {
            $('#checkboxContainer').show();
            $('#confirmCheckbox').prop('checked',false);
            $('#confirmButton').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('#checkboxContainer').hide();
            $('#confirmButton').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        $('#confirmCheckbox').change(function () {
            $('#confirmButton').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
        });


         
        $('#confirmButton').click(function (e) {
           
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success == 1) {
                    location.reload();
                }
                else {
                    $("#errorContainer").html('<p> Errore:' + result.error + '</p>')
                    $("#checkboxContainer").hide();
                    $('#confirmMessage').hide();
                   
                    $('#confirmButton').hide();
                }
            },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    $("#errorContainer").html('<p> Errore:' + error + '</p>')
                    $("#checkboxContainer").hide();
                    $('#confirmMessage').hide();
                
                $('#confirmButton').hide();
            }
        });
        });
    });

});
```

View

```
@using GESTPREF.Models.ViewModels
@using GESTPREF.Models.Enums
@using GESTPREF.Helpers


@model  IEnumerable<GruppoDisplayViewModel>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Elenco gruppi/livelli";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>



@{

    var badgeClasses = new Dictionary<StatoRecord, string>()
{
        { StatoRecord.Attivo, "badge bg-success" },
        { StatoRecord.Inattivo, "badge bg-warning text-dark" },
        { StatoRecord.Cancellato , "badge bg-danger" }
    };
}


<div class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center mb-2">

    @Html.BootstrapActionLink("Crea", "Create", "Gruppi", "bi bi-plus-circle", "Crea nuovo gruppo",null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

</div>

<table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
    <thead class="table-light text-dark">
        <tr>
            <td>Gruppo</td>
            <td>Livelli</td>
            <td>Stato</td>
            <td>Azioni</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var gruppo in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="align-top">
                    <table class="table-sm table-borderless">
                        <tr>
                            <td><i>@gruppo.Codice</i></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="fw-bold">@gruppo.Nome</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table class="table-sm table-borderless">
                        @foreach (var livello in gruppo.Livelli)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td><i>@livello.Codice</i></td>

                                <td class="fw-bold">@livello.Nome</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="@badgeClasses[@gruppo.Stato]">@gruppo.Stato.ToString()</span>
                </td>
                <td>

                    @if (gruppo.Stato == StatoRecord.Attivo)
                    {
                        @Html.BootstrapActionLink("", "Edit", "Gruppi", "bi bi-pencil", "Modifica gruppo",
                       routeValues: new { id = gruppo.Id },
                       htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" })

                        @Html.Raw("&nbsp");


                        @Html.BootstrapActionLink("", "Disattiva", "Gruppi", "bi bi-toggle-on", "Disattiva gruppo",
                          routeValues: new { id = gruppo.Id },
                          htmlAttributes: new
                          {
                              @class = "btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm",
                              data_bs_toggle = "modal",
                              requires_confirmation = "true"
                          })

                    }
                    else if (gruppo.Stato == StatoRecord.Inattivo)
                    {
                        @Html.BootstrapActionLink("", "Attiva", "Gruppi", "bi bi-toggle-off", "Attiva gruppo",
                          routeValues: new { id = gruppo.Id },
                          htmlAttributes: new
                          {
                              @class = "btn btn-outline-success btn-sm",
                              data_bs_toggle = "modal",
                              requires_confirmation = "true",
                          })

                        @Html.Raw("&nbsp");

                        @Html.BootstrapActionLink("", "Cancella", "Gruppi", "bi bi-trash", "Cancella gruppo",
                          routeValues: new { id = gruppo.Id },
                          htmlAttributes: new
                          {
                              @class = "btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm",
                              data_bs_toggle = "modal",                              
                              requires_confirmation = "true",
                              data_delete = "true"
                          })

                    }

                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>



<div id="confirmModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="confirmModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-keyboard="false" data-bs-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Conferma operazione</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Chiudi"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="confirmMessage">Sei sicuro di voler procedere?</p>

                <div id="checkboxContainer" style="display: none;">
                    <p class="text-danger">ATTENZIONE : La cancellazione è un'operazione irreversibile!</p>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="confirmCheckbox">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="confirmCheckbox">Ho capito e confermo</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="errorContainer"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Annulla</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="confirmButton" disabled>Conferma</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/confirm-modal.js"></script>

}
```

I'he changed my code as below:

```
$(function () {

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });



    $('a[data-bs-toggle="modal"][requires-confirmation]').on('click', function (e) {
        //e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        
       

        var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
        

        var hasDataDelete = $(this).is('[data-delete]');
        var deleteAction = $(this).attr('data-delete') === 'true';


        $('#confirmModal').modal('show');

        $("#errorContainer").hide();
        $('#confirmMessage').show();
        $('#confirmButton').show();


        if (deleteAction) {
            $('#checkboxContainer').show();
            $('#confirmCheckbox').prop('checked',false);
            $('#confirmButton').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('#checkboxContainer').hide();
            $('#confirmButton').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        $('#confirmCheckbox').change(function () {
            $('#confirmButton').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
        });


    });


    $('#confirmButton').on('click',function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success == 1) {
                    location.reload();
                }
                else {
                    $("#errorContainer").html('<p> Errore:' + result.error + '</p>')
                    $("#checkboxContainer").hide();
                    $('#confirmMessage').hide();

                    $('#confirmButton').hide();
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                $("#errorContainer").html('<p> Errore:' + error + '</p>')
                $("#checkboxContainer").hide();
                $('#confirmMessage').hide();

                $('#confirmButton').hide();
            }
        });
    });

});
```

This is what I want to have happen:

1. user click the link (href has the url for the actionmethod to call)
2. The modal confirm dialog is opened
3. The request will be sent to the server only if the user clicks the confirm button

With my previous code, if I understand what @Salman said, every time I am adding an event to the same button so there are multiple requests sent.

But now in my new code, obviously, the url vriable is not defined and no request are sent.

Comment: I would not advice you to bind a click event inside another click event

Comment: `.click` does not overwrite existing click handler, it adds. That is what is causing two requests on second click, three on third and so on. Re-arrange your code, dont attach click handlers inside click handlers.

Comment: I modified my code adding e.stopPropagatio(), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: what I want is to intercept the click of some actionlinks of the view. How should I change my code?

Comment: When you click an `a[requires-confirmation]` item, add some kind of class to the clicked element, or set a global variable with the URL, after that the confirmation click handler should locate the same element or access the same global variable.

Comment: I solved with a global variable. Thanks!

Comment: PS (offtopic) `Event.stopPropagation()` should only be used for testing and only if you really, really know what you're doing. An app and its third party scripts should be always notified about events happening in their lifecycle. Never, ever use stopPropagation(). Not in jQuery neither in JS. You can even forget it exists - until the day you'll really, really need it. There's always other means to achieve the desired without using this method.

Comment: Besides that, `.on` and `.off` methods are better (properly) used like `const myClickFn = (evt) => { /*entire click code here*/ };` then you use `$myElement.on("click", myClickFn)` and to remove that specific function from the listener you use `$myElement.off("click", myClickFn)` - by specifying the function as argument. Not by just doing `$myElement.off("click")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
$('#confirmButton').click(function (e) {
```

You are adding a new event listener every time the user clicks a link, so you end up with many click listeners on the same button.

You should do something like this:

```
$('#confirmButton').off('click').on('click', function (e) {
```

This will remove the previous click event listener and add a new one.

Here's some docs on [off](https://api.jquery.com/off/) and [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/). 'On' is just the new/preferred way to add event listeners since it is more consistent. And off will remove the selected event listener.